# How can I ensure iOS 13 modal view controllers present the right status bar colour?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios13, modalviewcontroller, uistatusbar

With the [new iOS 13 view controller changes](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e), view controllers are being presented that don't cover the whole screen. They instead leave a black space at the top. However, the system status bar is not changing colour automatically. When I present a modal view controller, the status bar is staying with now-invisible black text (and a green battery which looks super weird in the middle of nowhere).

How do I make the bar behave in the same way as within Apple's apps, where the bar animates to different colour when a modal popup appears?

I've tried setting `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` to true on my modal controllers, to no luck.

The bar in my presenting view controller is a UINavigationBar, and is not part of a navigation controller. The presenting VC is its delegate, and I've overridden `position(for bar: UIBarPositioning)` to return .topAttached.

I've tried presenting the modal with `.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet` and without setting .modalPresentationStyle at all. Neither worked.

Broken:

[image: broken view controller]

The presenting VC:

[image: the presenting view controller]

Expected Behaviour:

[image: ![expected behaviour, as shown in calendar app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

The modal view controllers need to have `VC.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = false`. This is the default but if, like me, you set it to something else, make sure it's false!

You need to ensure that `View controller-based status bar appearance` in your info.plist is set to `YES`. I'd messed around with it in an attempt to make my status bar the right colour but having it set to `NO` was a problem.